# x86 assembler adding

Tags: assembly, x86

I am a newbie on assembly and probably this question has a very basic answer but i really can't figure it out. As the result of this code AL gets the value FE. Why is not 00 ?

```
MOV BL,0ff;
MOV AL,0ff;
ADD AL,BL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because FF + FF = 1FE. So, AL will be FE, and your carry flag will be set (1).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting 0xFE because 0xFF + 0xFF = 0x1FE. The lower byte is 0xFE, obviously.